# Unexpected substitution behavior

Tags: substitute, string-manipulation

I need to put a comma between any two digits in a string of digits. For example, I want this

```
12345678910
```

to become this

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,0
```

The approach I took was the following

```
s/\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)/\1,\2/g
```

Strangely enough, the substitution command above when applied to the string in the example gives

```
1,23,45,67,89,10
```

If I apply the substitution command once again, it gives what I want. But **why just one instance of the command don't work?**

The `vim` version I'm using is

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Mar 18 2020 18:29:15)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> why just one instance of the command don't work?

Obviously, the string is parsed as `(12)(34)(56)(78)(91)0` --> `1,2 3,4 5,6 7,8 9,1 0`

A possible solution is `s/\d\d\@=/\0,/g`. See `:h /\@=`.

Comment: This ```\@=``` thing is very nifty. Didn't know of it, though. Thanks!

Comment: Or `s/\d\ze./&,/g`. A little shorter, maybe a little more efficient (not that one would notice with such small inputs). On the con side, you want to make sure there are only  numbers (otherwise `s/\d\ze\d/&,/g`).